# Only part of my QGraphicsTextItem is shown in my scene. To solve the problem i want to change the size of the boundingRect

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

As described above I have a scene with several items on it in which I want to add a QgraphicstextItem. Of that item only see the first few lines of pixels no matter where on the scene I put it (See Picture).
As there is no other object in front of the QGarhicsTextItem the only reason I can think of for it not being shown completely is that the boundingrect is too small. I checked the size of it and its width is only 8.
Why does my boundingRect not change its size?
Main.cpp

```
RandomNumber* randNum = new RandemNumber;
randNum->setPlainText("Hello"); 
randNum->setPostion(2100,2100);
randNum->boundingRect().adjust(2000,2000,2100,2100);
sce[n][1]e->addItem(randNum);
qDebug() << randNum->boundingRect().width;
```

My RandomNumber.cpp

```
    prepareGeometryChange();
    boundingRect().adjust(2000,2000,2100,2100);
    qDebug() << boundingRect().width;
```

Neither works. Both qDebugs return 8 as the width.
Thanks for your Help

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [QGraphicsTextItem::adjustSize()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicstextitem.html#adjustSize) after setting its text?

Comment: Btw. your code fragments are not much helpful. Better would be a [mcve] everybody could try on their own.

Comment: The doc. is a bit sparse. To be sure, I had a look into the source code of [QGraphicsTextItem::adjustSize()](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/graphicsview/qgraphicsitem.cpp.html#_ZN17QGraphicsTextItem10adjustSizeEv) and finally ended up in `QTextDocument::adjustSize()` which in turn determines the visual extent of the text by `QFontMetrics`. TL;DR: You should give `QGraphicsTextItem::adjustSize()` a try...

Comment: QGraphicsTextItem::adjustSize() sadly does not work

Comment: As previously requested you should edit your question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, have you got an updates?

Comment: no i have chosen a completely different path

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, OP didn't provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Nevertheless (and out of curiosity), I made an MCVE on my own:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  QGraphicsView qCanvas;
  qCanvas.resize(320, 240);
  QGraphicsScene qGScene;
  QGraphicsTextItem *pQGTextItem = qGScene.addText("Hello");
  qCanvas.setScene(&qGScene);
  qCanvas.show();
  // install timer
  const char* texts[] = {
    "Hello World!",
    "Hello Qt!",
    "Hello C++",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
  };
  const size_t nTexts = std::size(texts);
  size_t iText = 0;
  QTimer qTimer;
  qTimer.setInterval(1000);
  QObject::connect(&qTimer, &QTimer::timeout,
    [&]() {
      pQGTextItem->setPlainText(texts[iText++]);
      //pQGTextItem->adjustSize();
      iText %= nTexts;
    });
  qTimer.start();
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Output:

[image: GIF Animation of testQGraphicsViewQGraphicsTextItem]

The quite long "Lorem ipsum" sample text doesn't fit in but is shown. (Please, note the scrollbar which is added.)

Afterwards, I un-commented the `pQGTextItem->adjustSize();`.

Output:

[image: GIF Animation of testQGraphicsViewQGraphicsTextItem (with pQGTextItem->adjustSize())]

**TL;DR:**

- The size of `QGraphicsTextItem` is adjusted when new text is set.
- The size can be adjusted more aesthetically calling [QGraphicsTextItem::adjustSize()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicstextitem.html#adjustSize).

Answer (score 0):

`randNum->boundingRect().adjust(2000,2000,2100,2100);` and `boundingRect().adjust(2000,2000,2100,2100);` are pointless, you modify temporary copy of the object returned from the function. Notice that `boundingRect()` is defined as `const` - you can not use it to modify internal state of your object.

`adjustSize` should work, unless you overriden `boundingRect()` method, which is not neccessary.

Maybe you dont even need `RandomNumber` class, you can just use `QGraphicsTextItem`.

Comment: Thanks for you effort guys i know that my question was everything but perfect :/.
As i tried you answers i found out that with 
QGraphicsTextItem * randNum = ... 
the whole text is displayed. So the problem seems to be the size of the rect created with the class RandomNumber.